# directx: shader constant buffer initial value

Tags: directx, hlsl

if I have a constant buffer in my shader like
    cbuffer buffer
    { 
        float4 vector;
    };
what is the value of vector if I forgot to call SetConstantBuffers to set its value in c++ (or pass a nullptr for it in SetConstantBuffers). will it be initialized to zero or be any undefined value? in my test it is always zero but I want to know if that is defined by document

Comment: I tried, but i can't find any document for that situation...

Comment: Officially it's undefined behavior...